# FreeIPA replica - unable to login via web UI

Tags: ldap, kerberos, freeipa

I've installed a freeipa replica (almalinux-8-4.9.12) from my master (centos-7-4.6.8). Both running in docker. On web UI login I get `Login failed due to an unknown reason.` error.

And any ipa command fails with

```
ipa: DEBUG: Loading Index file from '/var/lib/ipa-client/sysrestore/sysrestore.index'
ipa: DEBUG: Loading StateFile from '/var/lib/ipa-client/sysrestore/sysrestore.state'
ipa: DEBUG: Loading StateFile from '/var/lib/ipa-client/sysrestore/sysrestore.state'
ipa: DEBUG: failed to find session_cookie in persistent storage for principal 'my.user@EXAMPLE.COM'
ipa: DEBUG: trying https://ipa-replica01.example.com/ipa/json
ipa: DEBUG: Created connection context.rpcclient_140546929970200
ipa: DEBUG: [try 1]: Forwarding 'schema' to json server 'https://ipa-slave01.example.com/ipa/json'
ipa: DEBUG: New HTTP connection (ipa-replica01.example.com)
ipa: DEBUG: HTTP connection destroyed (ipa-replica01.example.com)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipaclient/remote_plugins/__init__.py", line 120, in get_package
    plugins = api._remote_plugins
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute '_remote_plugins'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 724, in single_request
    if not self._auth_complete(response):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipalib/rpc.py", line 674, in _auth_complete
    message=u"No valid Negotiate header in server response")
ipalib.errors.KerberosError: No valid Negotiate header in server response
ipa: DEBUG: Destroyed connection context.rpcclient_140546929970200
ipa: ERROR: No valid Negotiate header in server response
```

Any help would be much appreciated